# How can use CGFloat in Swift?

Tags: swift, cgfloat

```
var posinonY:Float = Float(y) + Float(pipeDown.size.height) + Float(verticalPipeGap)
pipeDown.position = CGPointMake(0.0, Float(posinonY))
```

I get this error:

> "NSNumber' is not a subtype of 'CGFloat'"

Why?

---

#### Edit:

CGFLoat need double type

```
pipeDown.position = CGPointMake(0.0,  Double(posinonY))
```

this is ok.

Answer (score 39):

Use `CGFloat(number)` instead of `Float(number)`

```
pipeDown.position = CGPointMake(0.0, CGFloat(posinonY))
```

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue, but isn't this done for the developer for 5s? When I select 5s as the simulator, the problem goes away, when I switch back to an iphone 5 simulator, I get "NSNumber not a subtype of CGFloat"

Comment: @aleclarson, Xcode could prompt you how to fix it, it's not a shame absolutely

Comment: Just use CGFloats for all such calculations for Core Graphics. Then you do not need the casts either. Do not fight the system.

Answer (score 7):

Since `CGFloat` is not a `Double` on 32bit, it becomes hard to use CGGeometry and frameworks like CoreGraphics or SpriteKit. This library makes it a little easier and hopefully Apple takes care of it soon.

I wrote this to help out
https://github.com/seivan/ScalarArithmetic

But if you want to just make it work without dependencies use `var myFloat:CGFloat` explicitly, and make sure to cast any `Double` (numbers that are type inferred) to `CGFloat`
2.0 is inferred to be a Double and won't play along with the `CG-Structs` on 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

As in **Swift 4**

use

```
CGPoint(x: 12.0, y: 100.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CGFloat(Float).
Ex: -- `CGFloat(100.0)`.
We can use CGFloat in :

```
self.collectionHeader.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(100.0)).isActive = true
```