# Should we be using CGFloat for all floating point numbers in Swift?

Tags: swift

After watching a lot of the WWDC videos and reading through the Swift iBook, I came away with the impression that `CGFloat` was somewhat... legacy, due to the emphasis on `Int` and `Double/Float`. Perhaps somewhat comparable to `NSString` vs `String`.

I wrote a bit of code with the latter, and `Double` won't compile on non-64 bit devices. `Int` seems fine, though.

Should we still be using `CGFloat` for all math? Has anyone found anything that would indicate we'd be able to use the native Swift numerics? Because right now they're essentially unusable outside of scripts.

Comment: This is a known problem, they are working to fix Double/Float vs CGFloat related issues...See https://github.com/ksm/SwiftInFlux#numerical-data-type-conversion-eg-cgfloat-and-swift-doubleswift-float

Comment: *"Double won't compile on non-64 bit devices"* - this is not true. But on 32-bit devices, `Double` is 64-bit and `CGFloat = Float` is 32-bit, and you have to cast explicitly between them.

Comment: Martin: That is inaccurate; on 64-bit devices, `CGFloat = Double = 64-bit`. That's the problem: you cannot assume CGFloat is Double or Float, because it can be either, and Swift's strictness with numeric types turns this into a headache.

Comment: @WesCampaigne: I just said that on *32-bit devices*, Double = 64-bit and CGFloat = Float = 32-bit. What is inaccurate about that?

Comment: Closely related: [Swift numerics and CGFloat, CGPoint, CGRect, etc.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24108827)

Comment: Oh, sorry, never mind. I missed your "But on 32-bit devices" and consequently misunderstood the point of your comment. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Chris Lattner](https://devforums.apple.com/message/998222#998222), they recognize this problem and will have an official solution soon. I'd wait until this solution is fixed before deciding whether or not to use CGFloat.

> We're aware of this problem and consider it to be serious: we are
>   evaluating several different solutions right now and will roll one out
>   in a later beta.  As you notice, you can cope with this today by
>   casting to Double.  This is inelegant but effective :-)

Comment: How is it effective? I'm using `Double` now and it seems to choke on 32 bit devices.

Comment: @DougSmith: Can you post some concrete code demonstrating the problem?

Comment: You're right, I think I just wasn't casting universally. Thanks Martin.

Comment: @MartinR So what is the solution in the post connor linked to? https://devforums.apple.com/message/998222#998222 How do you make that initial code block work on both 32 bit and 64 bit?

Comment: @DougSmith: With `let (dx,dy) = (CGFloat (x), CGFloat(y))` the code compiles on both. - In fact that particular problem seems unrelated to "CGFloat different on 32/64-bit" to me. If CGFloat were Double on all archs then you also would have to cast the *integers* x, y to Double.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the problem when I was "fetching" from UserDefaults.

I saved float data like:

```
let floatValue: CGFloat = 1.3
UserDefaults.standard.set(floatValue, forKey: "Key")
```

Then I wanted to fetch it and parse it as a `CGFloat`

```
let floatValue = CGFloat(UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "Key"))
```

It made from **1.3** value - **1.29999**...

So when you save/load to/from UserDefaults you should use Float. Otherwise, I use CGFloat and there is no problem with it.