# Understanding the rules for conversion in swift

Tags: swift

I'm just reading through the Swift book from Apple and am a little confused about implicit conversion.
In one example there is this:

```
let mynum: Float = 4
```

and then immediately after it says: "Values are never implicitly converted to another type."

Whats going on here? They just implicitly converted an `Int` literal into a `Float` and then they are saying that values are never implicitly converted? Can anyone explain what the rule/exception is here?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["CGFloat is not convertible to Int" when trying to calculate an expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27461801/cgfloat-is-not-convertible-to-int-when-trying-to-calculate-an-expression)

Comment: @matt different question

Comment: Not at all, and see my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27461821/341994 If you think that doesn't answer your question, think some more.

Comment: @matt Ah, it does seem to answer my question. Yet the question asked is not clearly the same IMO.

Comment: But if you'd consulted it, you'd have gotten your answer. That's what `duplicate` is about. It means "don't ask a question you don't have to ask". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`4` is not a "value". It is a literal. So it can be interpreted however Swift likes. There is nothing to "convert"; it is used to *create* the value, but the created value will be a Float, because that is what you asked for.

But now try this:

```
let i : Int = 4
let mynum: Float = i
```

Ooooops.

To put it another way:

```
let mynum: Float = 4
```

is *interpreted* as

```
let mynum = Float(4) // we are _creating_ the value
```

But if we start with `i`, *you* have to create the value:

```
let i : Int = 4
let mynum: Float = Float(i)
```

Swift won't do that for you.

**BONUS LESSON** Hold my beer and watch *this*:

```
struct Dog : IntegerLiteralConvertible {
    var number : Int?
    init(integerLiteral: Int) {
        self.number = integerLiteral
    }
}
let dog : Dog = 42
```

Float works like that, sort of.

Comment: So only variables/constants are considered to be "value"'s? What are the rules for literals (is it documented somewhere)?

Comment: Mmmmmm, well, it's all about the `IntegerLiteralConvertible` protocol. I don't think you really want to go there....

Comment: If you get really curious, see the Swift header, where Float is extended to adopt `IntegerLiteralConvertible`. That means you can supply an Integer literal where a Float is expected, and a special corresponding `init` will be called.

Comment: Ahah it would bug me if i didn't have some understanding of what is going on, i shall look it up. Thanks