# '[CFString!]' is not convertible to '[String]'

Tags: ios, swift, cfstring

Before Swift 1.2 I had following array:

```
private let phoneLabels = [
    kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel,
    kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel,
    kABWorkLabel,
    kABHomeLabel,
    kABPersonPhoneMainLabel,
    kABPersonPhoneHomeFAXLabel,
    kABPersonPhoneWorkFAXLabel,
    kABPersonPhonePagerLabel,
    kABOtherLabel
] as [String]
```

After I updated Xcode to 6.3, I can't have it like that:

```
private let phoneLabels = [
    kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel,
    kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel,
    kABWorkLabel,
    kABHomeLabel,
    kABPersonPhoneMainLabel,
    kABPersonPhoneHomeFAXLabel,
    kABPersonPhoneWorkFAXLabel,
    kABPersonPhonePagerLabel,
    kABOtherLabel
] as! [String]
```

Because compiler shows me an error: `'[CFString!]' is not convertible to '[String]'`.

I can probably convert each `CFString` to `String` in array, but maybe there is an easier and more readable way to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
private let phoneLabels = [
    kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel,
    kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel,
    kABWorkLabel,
    kABHomeLabel,
    kABPersonPhoneMainLabel,
    kABPersonPhoneHomeFAXLabel,
    kABPersonPhoneWorkFAXLabel,
    kABPersonPhonePagerLabel,
    kABOtherLabel
] as [AnyObject] as! [String]
```

Comment: And you might want to file a bug report on this; I have. In my view, Swift should just "know" that a CFString is an NSString is a String. Nevertheless, this change _is_ consistent with the announced changes in Swift 1.2, so Apple may decide you don't have a case. You no longer get automatic implicit coercion of NSString to String, which is what your earlier code relied on.

Comment: This is ridiculous. Not the answer, the syntax. Swift is (still) terrible at some places.

Comment: One mark of a good language is allowing the developer to concentrate on the problem being solved, not the syntax the compiler requires.

Comment: @Zaph That train left the station in June 2014, when Swift decided to have the worst numerics handling in the history of computer languages (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108827/swift-numerics-and-cgfloat-cgpoint-cgrect-etc) Still, it's a lot better (and safer) than Objective-C, which _really_ required the developer to concentrate on the syntax (can you say "semicolon"?)...

Comment: Yep, `[AnyObject] as! [String]` is so much beter than `;`. P.S. I had already up-voted your question. ;-)

Comment: Swift is a terrible language when you beyond the cookie cutter UI work. Anywhere where C/C++ interop is required, Swift being terrible is putting it mildly.

Comment: or a bit more constrained `as [NSString] as! [String]`